# find the type of answer in java

Tags: java, nlp-question-answering

Sorry if this question is duplicate, but I have not found the answer. I want to find the type of question using java. The problem is that I do not know how to find the type of question from the question which the user will be submit.

For example:

```
Where is the Louvre Museum?

The type of this question is location.
```

Anybody has an idea how to do it?

Comment: Make a `HashMap<String,String>`. First parameter is the keyword ("where") - second parameter is the Answer-String. Use: `if (hashmap.contains(sentence.split(" ")))`. and so on... really easy.

Comment: yes thanks for your answer, but if the question had two or more type of answer what can I do for this issue or that is not impossible?

Comment: @user4462040 The idea is that you look at the sort of questions you have for each type of answer, and find the common keywords for each type, e.g.: "who" => person, "what" => object,  "where" => location, "when" => time, and so on.  If the question/answer mapping you have to deal with is not this simple then you might want to look into some Natural Language Processing methods.

Comment: which are the NLP methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using user input:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)
```

ask for the input question:

```
System.out.println("Question:");
String[] q = s.nextLine().split(" "); //changing user input to word array
String w = q[0].toLowerCase();
```

check for question words:

```
switch(w){
    case "where":
        //print out "this is a location question"
        break;
    case "who":
        //print out "this is a who question"
        break;

    ... //keep on doing this for all words

    default:
        //print out "this is not a valid question"
        break;

}
```

if there are multiple:

```
System.out.println("Question:");
String[] q = s.nextLine().split(" "); 
List<String> a = Arrays.asList(q);
```

Check if it contains the question words:

```
if(a.contains("Who"))
    //print out "Who question"
if(a.contains("Where"))
    //print out "Where question"
```

Comment: yes I have done like this, but I trying to implement a question answering system and I want to find the type of question to make more specific the search for each question.

Comment: @user4462040 elaborate?

Comment: yes i will try and i will get back

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a dictionary list, which will contain pairs of question type, and specific substrings corresponding to the question type, for example:

```
"yes/no", "is"
"location",  {"where", "how far", "direction"}
"time", {"when", "how long"}
```

you get the idea. It could be done very easily using mapping, for example a HashMap, for this case:

```
HashMap <String, String[]> hm = new HashMap <String, String[]>();
```

You can replace

```
String[]
```

with

```
ArrayList <String>
```

as well.